# Why was Sarah Kerrigan abandoned by Arcturus Mengsk?

Tags: novel, video-games, character-motivation, starcraft

Sarah Kerrigan, former Terran Ghost and later the Queen of Blades, leader of the Zerg, was a major character in both the *Starcraft I* and *Starcraft II* video game series and has appeared in several novels that followed: *Liberty's Crusade, Queen of Blades, Shadow of the Xel'naga,* and *Shadow Hunters.*

Why was she abandoned on Antiga Prime by Arcturus Mengsk and left to be infested by the Zerg?

Comment: I assumed it was because Kerrigan's position was being overrun and Mengsk didn't want to expend the resources to dig her out. But the cut-scene where that occurs doesn't explicitly say so, and Mengsk's body language seems almost smug when he gives the order to move out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Having just replayed StarCraft 1 up to this betrayal, it was very apparent why Mengsk did it.

In the 3 missions preceding the betrayal Kerrigan she was told to use the psi-emitters to lure the zerg to a smaller confederate outpost. She did it but under heavy protest.

> **Kerrigan** - I'm having doubts about this, Arcturus. I
>      just don't think anyone deserves to have
>      the Zerg unleashed on them.
>
> **Mengsk** - I know you have personal feelings about
>      this, but you can't let your past cloud your
>      judgement. Carry out your orders, lieutenant.

later at the end of the mission.

> **Kerrigan** - Psi-Emitter in place. Just promise me we'll
>      never do anything like this again.
>
> **Mengsk** - We will do whatever it takes to save
>      humanity. Our responsibility is too great to
>      do any less.

In the very next mission we make a breach in Tarsonis' defences, presumibly to send a strike force down to the planet. instead after the Breach Mengsk again deploys psi-emitters, and lures billions of zerg to the planet. This causes a major rift between with Kerrigan/Raynor on one side, and Mengsk on the other.

> **DUKE**
>
> This is Duke. The emitters are secured and    on-line.
>
> **KERRIGAN**
>
> Who authorized the use of Psi-Emitters?
>
> **MENGSK**
>
> I did, lieutenant.
>
> **KERRIGAN**
>
> What? The Confederates on Antiga were    bad enough, but now you're
>   going to use    the Zerg against an entire planet? This is insane.
>
> **RAYNOR**
>
> She's right, man. Think this through.
>
> **MENGSK**
>
> I have thought it through. Believe me.    You all have your orders.
>   Carry them out.

Following Kerrigans damming of Mengsk he sends her on 1 more mission, a mission to stop the Protoss who are unknowingly defending the remaining confederates on Tarsonis.

> **Mengsk :**
>
> If they engage the Zerg, the    Confederates may escape.
>   Commander, send Lieutenant    Kerrigan with a strike force to
>   engage the Protoss. Captain Raynor    and General Duke will stay
>   behind    with the command ship.
>
> **Raynor :**
>
> First you sell out every person on    this world to the Zerg, then
>   you    ask us to go up against the    Protoss? And you're goin' to
>   send    Kerrigan down there with no    backup?
>
> **Mengsk :**
>
> I have absolute confidence in    Kerrigan's ability to hold off the
>   Protoss.
>
> **Raynor :**
>
> This is bullshit. Kerrigan, are you    reading this?
>
> **Kerrigan :**
>
> I heard. I'm going down there.    Arcturus knows what he's doing. I
>   can't back out on him now.
>
> **Raynor :**
>
> Funny. I never thought of you as    anyone's martyr.
>
> **RAYNOR**
>
> Why are you doing this, Kerrigan? Look. I    know about your past. I
>   mean, I've heard    the rumors. I know you were a part of those
>   experiments with the Zerg; that Mengsk    came and saved you, but you
>   don't owe    him this! Hell, I've saved you butt    plenty of times.
>
> **KERRIGAN**
>
> Jimmy, drop the knight-in-shining-armor routine.    It suits you
>   sometimes. Just not ... not now. I don't    need to be rescued. I know
>   what I'm doing. The    Protoss are coming to destroy the entire
>   planet, not    just the Zerg. I know that because ... well I just know
>   it. I am a Ghost, remember? Once we've dealt with    the Protoss, we
>   can do something about the Zerg.    Arcturus will come around. I know
>   he will.
>
> **RAYNOR**
>
> I hope you're right, darlin'. Good huntin'!

This mission is clearly a set up for Kerrigan, with Raynor stating, your going to send her in by herself, with no support, and Mengsk replying, dont worry she'll be fine. Obviously at the conclusion of this mission Mengsk again pulls a fast one and states, uh, cant get to her sorry Jim.

> **KERRIGAN**
>
> This is Kerrigan. We've neutralized the    Protoss, but there's a wave
>   of Zerg    advancing on this position. We need    immediate evac.
>
> **MENGSK**
>
> Belay that order. We're moving out.
>
> **RAYNOR**
>
> What? You're not just gonna leave them?
>
> **MENGSK**
>
> All ships prepare to move away from    Tarsonis on my mark.
>
> **KERRIGAN**
>
> Uh, boys? How about that evac?
>
> **RAYNOR**
>
> Damn you, Arcturus! Don't do this.
>
> **MENGSK**
>
> It's done. Helmsman, signal the fleet, and    take us out of orbit.
>   Now!
>
> **KERRIGAN**
>
> Commander? Jim? What the hell's going on    up there-

So with the books and extra material aside, they make it clear in game that Mengsk betrays  Kerrigan because she is quickly becoming a tool he can no longer use, with her arguments and opposition to his plans.

Comment: This really makes we want to spend next weekend playing through the SC/BW campaign. Dangit.

Comment: I'd have made this the accepted answer... While the other one makes a lot of sense and is a good answer, that novel was written a good while after the game and (canon or not), it's doubtful that was in the minds of the creators when they were making the game, this answer clearly depicts Sarah becoming a "loose end"

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Purely relies on the original game, includes all conversation texts. Cleared my mind about the same question after years. Good piece of work.

Comment: I agree with the comments here that this should be (and is) the accepted answer. I have upvoted both answers though.

Comment: Here is that episode in StarCraft 1: [Starcraft Remastered Sarah Kerrigan Betrayal HD - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVuFoXfwZs4 "Starcraft Remastered Sarah Kerrigan Betrayal HD - YouTube")

Answer (score 18):

**Sarah Kerrigan, during her time as a Confederate Ghost, assassinated Mengsk's parents and sister.**

When Korhal declared itself independent from the Confederacy, taking out the Mengsk family was one of their first actions, before they carpet-nuked the place as well.  Kerrigan led the team.

While Arcturus later retrieved her from an experimental facility (some of the initial tests confirming the link between Zerg and psionics like Ghosts were done on Kerrigan), she had only fragmentary memories of her time as an assassin at best.  She didn't recognize Arcturus or his name.  He did.  He befriended her and invited her to join the Sons of Korhal.  Over time some of her memory returned, and Mengsk used her to take out the other Ghosts who had performed the kills, but supposedly forgave her once the others were dead.

He was content to use her as a highly effective tool against the Confederacy that once employed her against him.  Once his victory over the Confederate capital Tarsonis was assured by psi-summoned Zerg, however, he coldly took his revenge by positioning her to assure the Zerg's success and then abandoning her.  That it saved some of his forces the effort of killing Zerg that were killing Confederates probably didn't hurt.

The Mengsk's assassination is covered in the tie-in novel *[I, Mengsk](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3466381-starcraft)* along with some of Arcturus' family history.  The start of Kerrigan and Mengsk's working relationship is shown in *[Starcraft: Uprising](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6403918-uprising)*.

Comment: This is mainly coming from wikia; I was familiar with the reason but not the details.  I'm trying to confirm the novels the events were covered in.  Will link soon.

Comment: +1 The assassination is verified at http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Arcturus_Mengsk: "He (Arcturus) told Kerrigan she was the third ghost, and the most important one - the one who had cut off his father's head. Yet he found her useful and kept her as a loyal member of the Sons of Korhal. Kerrigan's loyalty to him increased." So at this point, we have motivation, but not a validated canon reason. Still, this is more than I knew before.

Comment: I like your answer, but must relocate the green check mark.

Comment: @MajorStackings - fair enough, I gave the other answer an upvote myself.